# Determine AWS CodePipeline from CodeCommit source

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I'm working in an environment with hundreds of AWS CodePipeline resources built automatically by another pipeline. We're also using CodeCommit for all of our repositories. The pipelines are declared and built within an "environment" file across several "versions" of a parent pipeline builder. We have gotten to the point where we have literally hundreds of pipelines scattered across multiple accounts and regions.

The problem is this: when we find and work on a repository, make and push changes, it is nearly impossible to easily determine what pipeline builds from these changes. The naming scheme is not great and none of the pipelines have been tagged with information regarding their source repository. Currently it is not practical to go back and fix this issue. However, we would like to be able to easily determine what pipelines use a CodeCommit repository as their source.

So far, the standard method of finding these pipelines is to go through each parent pipeline environment, do search for the repository name that is used as the source in these environment files. This (typically) gives us the base name of the pipeline used; however, it's not always totally accurate.

Is there a tool that exists to help with this issue? Or is there something I'm missing inside the AWS console for finding this information? All the documentation I can find is about *creating* pipelines but not actually determining what pipeline is using a source repository.

The best solution I have come up with so far is to build a tool that uses the AWS SDK (or CLI) to list all pipelines in an account with `aws codepipeline list-pipelines`, iterate through the list of pipelines with `aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <NAME>`. This will return the details of  the pipeline that includes stage configurations. From the stage I can find the `Source` category, and from the configuration I can find the `RepositoryName`. If the repository name matches the one I'm searching for, it is added to a list. After all pipelines for an account have been searched, the list of pipelines can be printed to the console.

What I'm really hoping for is that a tool like this already exists and I don't have to write it myself but so far I've come up with nothing.

Comment: Not aware of any tools. As you mentioned, create a custom script by utilising AWS SDK. You will get repo information from pipelines as well as from CloudWatch event rules configured for the pipelines

Comment: @JyothishKumarS that's essentially what I did. Ended up taking less effort than expected.